# how to properly make an element 'disappear' on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am attempting to make a span element disappear on hover. Not working out to well.

Code: (CSS)

```
.list-item-note { 
    font-size:9px;  
    color:#666;
    font-style: italic;
}
.list-item-note:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Code: (HTML)

```
<div class="list-item"><a href="#">Link Here</a>
    <span class="list-item-note">(This disappear on hover)</span>
</div>
```

How can I make the item from class 'list-item-note' disappear when it's parent element is hovered over?

I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. At least i hope it can be done. As always thanks!

EDIT: When I hover over the parent element i would like it to disappear. That element being "list-item"
Question has been properly worded and solution has been found. Remove downvote?

Comment: Hiding an element means it is not hovered anymore, right?

Comment: You could use `opacity` for that.

Comment: Using opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/N45c2/

Comment: Not sure why the down vote but the question was solved below. It was an issue with which element to apply the the hover. Question is fixed and solution has been found. Remove the downvote?

Comment: There is a further issue beyond the `visibility: hidden` aspect or opacity. Give me a minute and I'll go beyond the two answers you have already given.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't able to solve the second issue you are now going to face, whether it be `visibility:` or `opacity:` ... I have to go, otherwise I'd keep trying to tweak it further. I included notes in my answer in case anyone else wants to tackle the deeper aspect I am pointing out.

Comment: Actually, I just tried @koenp's answer and that solves the flicker issue I mentioned also. Learned something about CSS's nuances here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the element that you want to hide will not have the :hover as soon as it is removed, making it appear again, etc.

You have a few options:

You could add the :hover to a parent element that itself is not removed like this:

```
.list-item:hover .list-item-note {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KA8KU/

Alternatively you could use an opacity trick: make the element invisible using opacity:

```
.list-item-note:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KA8KU/1/

Comment: Worked great. I see how i messed up there. Needed to apply to the parent element. Worked great. Will accept when times up. Thanks!

Comment: I added an alternative solution. Check what works best in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The way you intend it to be, that is about visibility actually:

```
.list-item-note:hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/ZKuXh/

Ok, the second problem which I tried to fix for you, if you use Chrome for example, is that whether you use opacity or visibility to make the text disappear... when your cursor is on the text itself, not the whitespace around the text, the text still appears. This is a toucher one to solve. I've tried using `display: inline-cell` and that sort of thing, but either way, if you pass your cursor over the individual characters, the hover appears to flicker.

**CONCEDE:** `opacity:` is actually the right way to go, because it does not have the flicker issue.